# Ubuntu Focal Fossa Installed but some leftover Eoan Ermine exists

Tags: upgrade, updates, wine, mysql

**Update: Solved by going to the Settings on the Update Manager and deselecting all the source checkboxes and changing the source to Main Server.**

A while back I had considerable difficulty upgrading my system from 19.04 to 20.04 and after it updated itself to 19.10 Eoan the lingering affects of multiple errors seem to keep it from updating so apparently the upgrade did not do everything it was supposed to do. For example, there a couple held packages that do not update and I've tried so many different things that I've forgotten what they were so apologies if this seems disjointed but I'll gladly update it with advice on what to do or try.

It was pointed out that there is a similar question about held packages and indeed that is the problem here too but the main issue is the Eoan reference and how to fix the overall update which failed on several levels, only part of which are the held packages.

Although I can't locate them at the moment, some of the errors related to 19.10 Eoan which I mentioned in the title and perhaps that's normal but I don't believe there should be such references.

```
apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
mysql-client/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10]
mysql-server/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10]
```

Some of the issues manifest themselves in not being able to update MySQL. Checking which version of mysql is installed . . .

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

it gives  gives errors when I try to upgrade it:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-client mysql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

There are also unmet dependencies that so not seem to want to update:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Other issues relating to WINE having stopped working (WINE applications do nothing when selected) and it seems to want Win32 which will not install.

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Of course I tried installing the dependencies separately but that also gives other errors as it seems that each depends upon something else.

I also installed and ran aptitude which corrected many things but not the held packages.

Update: In spite mysql and WINE errors, those packages seem to run.

Ideas?

Comment: The simplest way to fix all the problems would be to take a backup of the important files in the home folder, and perform a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused; as your title & when using codename you mention *eoan* (19.10) but in your description you mention *disco* 19.04 and *focal* 20.04.   Ubuntu 19.04 (*disco*) was QA-tested to upgrade to the next release (*eoan* or 19.10) and not skip a release and jump to *focal* or 20.04 so issues are more likely when you step outside of intended upgrade paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong version number but the message contained Eoan. Also, I am unaware that Ubuntu would let one step outside the intended upgrade path and I did not do anything in particular to do so.

Comment: Unfortunate the link posted was one of many dozens that I visited before posting here and it did not help. `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` seems to do nothing but I did not try installing aptitude.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1335943/edit): Fix the version names/numbers so others don't get confused. Add the complete output of `apt-cache policy` for the packages `mysql-client-8.0` and `libwine:i386`

Comment: Actually the version number was correct but somehow in trying to upgrade to 20.04 from 19.04, it got stuck in 19.10 leaving some hints of itself here and there. Maybe that's normal but I don't think so.